# Should I write multiple wrapper methods for functionality with limited possible options?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a method in a client library that is intended to, for example, set a status of something to one of a limited number of statuses, is it considered good practice to write a wrapper method for each possible status, or allow the user to just pass in the status they want as a parameter?

For example:

```
def set_success_status(commit):
  _set_status('success', commit)

def set_failure_status(commit):
  _set_status('failure', commit)

def _set_status(status, commit):
  # some logic to actually set the status
```

Comment: What's wrong with `set_status(status, commit)`?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking. Is there a best practice? I think `set_status()` is fine but someone on my team suggests these "helper" functions. I just don't see the point in them.

Comment: This is precisely the definition of an opinionated question and is hence off topic for SO. I feel your pain though, I hate writing more code than needed. Especially with the power of python's functions and arguments, why would you need more than one function? But that's my opinion.

Comment: Okay, that's fair enough! I was mainly hoping to find a specific best practice that I was unable to find searching elsewhere, but if this truly comes down to being an opinion then so be it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the status has any effect if not correctly assigned to one of the limited possibilities I would recommend multiple wrapper methods; however, if the status is purely informational and does not serve as a basis for future statements, then just having a regular `set_status(status, commit)` function would be more than enough.

Applying the multiple wrapper method could be useful for a number of reasons the most obvious of which being client error prevention, in addition to helping the client see all options in function autocomplete instead of having to look for documentation on the different `status` options available for use. In addition if you need to change the literal `status` string, you can do so without any client disruption by keeping the function's name the same.

In the end it comes down to the exact scenario and following currently set practices in the project. I do not see how multiple wrapper methods could do any harm though, and it solidifies every option as its own entity (which is reasonable since they are limited options), allowing you more flexibility in applying every `status`.